# updating row values where MULTIPLE column conditions are from a nested list

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, iterator, nested-lists

Part of the dataframe is attached below:

```
                   state  year 4rcsallmn  ... 4rcsndl90se dyslaw dyslawk0
30                Alaska  2015    212.79  ...        1.42    0.0        0
31               Arizona  2015    215.31  ...        1.42    2.0        0
32              Arkansas  2015    218.08  ...        1.99    2.0        0
33            California  2015    212.68  ...        1.65    2.0        0
34              Colorado  2015    224.02  ...        1.38    1.0        0
35           Connecticut  2015    228.95  ...        1.90    2.0        0
36              Delaware  2015    223.70  ...        1.39    2.0        0
37  District of Columbia  2015    212.31  ...        2.20    NaN        0
38                 DoDEA  2015    233.76  ...        2.06    NaN        0
39               Florida  2015    227.19  ...        1.63    2.0        0
40               Georgia  2015    222.01  ...        1.12    1.0        0
41                Hawaii  2015    215.12  ...        2.31    1.0        0
42              National  2013    221.83  ...        0.36    NaN        0
43               Alabama  2013    218.58  ...        1.38    1.0        0
44                Alaska  2013    209.35  ...        0.90    0.0        0
45               Arizona  2013    213.13  ...        2.20    2.0        0
46              Arkansas  2013    218.52  ...        1.19    2.0        0
47            California  2013    212.55  ...        2.12    2.0        0
48              Colorado  2013    226.66  ...        1.92    1.0        0
49           Connecticut  2013    229.58  ...        1.74    2.0        0
```

I added in a column of dyslawk0 that should be zero except for certain values of both state and year.
I started by setting all of the column to zero (df_4['dyslawk0'] = 0)

***The column dyslawk0 will not update with my multiple column conditions.***

I have a nested list of states and years in which if a row as that certain state and year combo, dyslawk0 should be updated to be a 1.

Here is my list

```
treat_year = [['Arizona', 2015],
              ['Arkansas', 2013],
              ['California', 2012],
              ['Connecticut', 2014],
              ['Delaware', 2014],
              ['Florida', 2017]]
```

and here is my code:

```
for pair in treat_year:
 df_4['dyslawk0'] = np.where(((df_4['state'] == pair[0]) & (df_4['year'] == pair[1])), 1, 0)
```

For example, the first with both Arizona and 2015 **should have dyslaw0 updated to 1.**

df.loc also does not work with a nested list:

```
for pair in treat_year:
  df_4.loc[((df_4['state'] == pair[0]) & (df_4['year'] == pair[1])), 'dyslawk0'] = 1
```

Let me know if this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: If still not working maybe column `year` is not filled by numbers, but by string repr of numbers, so need replace year to integrs for all solutions bellow:

```
df['year'] = df['year'].astype(int)
```

---

You can use trick - convert both columns to `MultiIndex` and then test index by  by [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html), last for map `True, False` to `1, 0` use [`Series.view`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.view.html) or[`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) :

```
df['dyslawk0'] = df.set_index(['state','year']).index.isin(treat_year).view('i1')
#alternative1
df['dyslawk0'] = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df[['state','year']]).isin(treat_year).view('i1')
#alternative2
df['dyslawk0'] = np.where(df.set_index(['state','year']).index.isin(treat_year), 1, 0)
print (df)
                   state  year  4rcsallmn  4rcsndl90se  dyslaw  dyslawk0
30                Alaska  2015     212.79         1.42     0.0         0
31               Arizona  2015     215.31         1.42     2.0         1
32              Arkansas  2015     218.08         1.99     2.0         0
33            California  2015     212.68         1.65     2.0         0
34              Colorado  2015     224.02         1.38     1.0         0
35           Connecticut  2015     228.95         1.90     2.0         0
36              Delaware  2015     223.70         1.39     2.0         0
37  District of Columbia  2015     212.31         2.20     NaN         0
38                 DoDEA  2015     233.76         2.06     NaN         0
39               Florida  2015     227.19         1.63     2.0         0
40               Georgia  2015     222.01         1.12     1.0         0
41                Hawaii  2015     215.12         2.31     1.0         0
42              National  2013     221.83         0.36     NaN         0
43               Alabama  2013     218.58         1.38     1.0         0
44                Alaska  2013     209.35         0.90     0.0         0
45               Arizona  2013     213.13         2.20     2.0         0
46              Arkansas  2013     218.52         1.19     2.0         1
47            California  2013     212.55         2.12     2.0         0
48              Colorado  2013     226.66         1.92     1.0         0
49           Connecticut  2013     229.58         1.74     2.0         0
```

Btw, your last solution for me working well:

```
for pair in treat_year:
  df.loc[((df['state'] == pair[0]) & (df['year'] == pair[1])), 'dyslawk0'] = 1

print (df)
                   state  year  4rcsallmn  4rcsndl90se  dyslaw  dyslawk0
30                Alaska  2015     212.79         1.42     0.0         0
31               Arizona  2015     215.31         1.42     2.0         1
32              Arkansas  2015     218.08         1.99     2.0         0
33            California  2015     212.68         1.65     2.0         0
34              Colorado  2015     224.02         1.38     1.0         0
35           Connecticut  2015     228.95         1.90     2.0         0
36              Delaware  2015     223.70         1.39     2.0         0
37  District of Columbia  2015     212.31         2.20     NaN         0
38                 DoDEA  2015     233.76         2.06     NaN         0
39               Florida  2015     227.19         1.63     2.0         0
40               Georgia  2015     222.01         1.12     1.0         0
41                Hawaii  2015     215.12         2.31     1.0         0
42              National  2013     221.83         0.36     NaN         0
43               Alabama  2013     218.58         1.38     1.0         0
44                Alaska  2013     209.35         0.90     0.0         0
45               Arizona  2013     213.13         2.20     2.0         0
46              Arkansas  2013     218.52         1.19     2.0         1
47            California  2013     212.55         2.12     2.0         0
48              Colorado  2013     226.66         1.92     1.0         0
49           Connecticut  2013     229.58         1.74     2.0         0
```